# Customise legend when using Google Charts API using Fusion Table as datasource

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-visualization

Using Google Charts API to create a column chart with a Google Fusion table as a datasource.

http://clairemiller.net/TableTest.html

However, to get it to recognise the columns in the query I've had to rename them as a single word, which means my legend looks a bit unhelpful.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Fusion Tables API Example: Google Chart Tools Bar Chart</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });

      function drawVisualization() {
        google.visualization.drawChart({
          containerId: 'visualization',
          dataSourceUrl: 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=',
          query: 'SELECT Name, GCSE09, GCSE10, GCSE11, GCSE12 FROM 16XitWt9yCjRFVGFj4h109dGA_9wLgqExVrF9sAk WHERE URN="100049"',
      chartType: 'ColumnChart',
      options: {
        title: '% gaining 5 A*-C GCSEs including English and Maths',
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Percentage'
        },
        hAxis: {
          title: ''
        }
      }
    });
  }

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="visualization"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to customise the legend so the text displayed is different to the column header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to query columns with spaces in the names.

Use " around  your string

use ' around the column names

```
  function drawVisualization() {
    google.visualization.drawChart({
      containerId: 'visualization',
      dataSourceUrl: 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=',
      query: "SELECT Name, 'GCSE09', 'GCSE10', 'GCSE11', 'GCSE12' FROM 16XitWt9yCjRFVGFj4h109dGA_9wLgqExVrF9sAk WHERE URN='100049'",
  chartType: 'ColumnChart',
  options: {
    title: '% gaining 5 A*-C GCSEs including English and Maths',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Percentage'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: ''
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, just couldn't get the combination right to get it to recognise column names with spaces in.